# Pthreads create argument passing

Tags: pthreads

I am trying to pass 2 arguments using a struct in the pthread_create method. One argument is for the total amount of threads active and the other one is for the id of the thread, which is the number it receives from theloop (i). The problem i have right now is that the argument_struct.id value has the same value when i use the run the for loop.

```
struct argument_struct {
int total_threads;
int id;
} argument_struct;


void * body(void *args)
{
    struct argument_struct *arguments = args;
    printf("Hello World! %i, %i \n", argument_struct.total_threads, argument_struct.id);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    const num_threads = 20;
    pthread_t thread[num_threads];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int i;

    /* Initiate the thread attributes */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    argument_struct.total_threads = num_threads;

    for (i=0; i<num_threads; i++)
    {
        argument_struct.id = i;
        pthread_create(&thread[i], &attr, &body, (void *)&argument_struct);
    }
```

output

```
Hello world! 20, 19
Hello world! 20, 19
Hello world! 20, 19
etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a race condition - by the time a thread gets to look at the structure it has been passed, the main thread has already reused that structure to pass to the next created thread.

There are several ways you could solve this:

1) have an array of `struct argument_struct` items (the array at least large enough for the number of threads), and use a separate element to pass to each newly created thread

2) store the `total_threads` value in a global that the threads can read.  There's no data race here, since the value isn't updated after it is initialized and the threads will only read it.  On the other hand you have a shared global which isn't a great idea to use as an interface, but might be OK for small programs. To avoid the problem with sharing the `id` element, just pass it directly by casting it to a `(void*)`.

3) dynamically allocate a new `struct argument_struct` to pass to each thread.  The thread will become the owner of the struct and will be responsible for freeing it.  This is probably the best solution generally (ie., the technique will work well even if you start passing in a large number or complex set of arguments).

4) Use something like a semaphore or condition variable to let the thread signal when it has finished using the passed in structure. The main thread should wait on that synchronization object before reusing the structure to create the next thread.  This might be overkill for your simple example, but again it'll work in situations of greater complexity (though I still think that passing in a dynamically allocated structure is simpler).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing each thread the same argument, which is why they all see the same value.